# Facebook Login error - Can't Load URL

Tags: facebook

I know this has been ask3d before but I have tried several of the posts but still cannot get it to work.  I am being forced to use strict mode for url redirects and no matter what I put for the domain nothing works.

```
<?php
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

// Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/*
 * Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
 */
$appId         = '********'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret     = '***************'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL   = 'https://www.themathouse.com/'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions = array('email');  //Optional permissions



$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Try to get access token
try {
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    }else{
          $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
     echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
     echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
}

?>
```

On the facebook app I have themathouse.com as the app domain and https://www.themathouse.com as the Valid OAuth redirect URIs.

When I try logging in with facebook I get the following error:

Graph returned an error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to upload an image showing the Facebook Loging settings but I do not have enough points.  I checked and the valid oauth redirect url is https://www.themathouse.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Redirect Url matches what is set in your App Settings, under **Facebook Login** -> **Settings** -> **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**

In this case, it seems to be `https://www.themathouse.com/`

**EDIT:** Also, as it seems that you are using the PHP SDK, make sure that you are using the currently latest version, 5.6.2, as this one fixed an issue present on 5.6.1 and older that may affect you.

Comment: I tried to upload an image showing the Facebook Loging settings but I do not have enough points. I checked and the valid oauth redirect url is themathouse.com

Comment: Added a comment about SDK version, another possible cause.
Make sure that your ouath redirect url matches exactly, including protocol and trailing slash.

Comment: That did it.  I had tried adding the full url but it had not worked but it was apparently the SDK.  I downloaded the latest version and that took care of the problem.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**THIS** worked for me!! (after fiddling with a bunch of stuff suggested on various forums, to no avail)

I updated the 'FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' file:
https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php and voila! Pesky login error fixed :)

(Oh, I also updated code for other recently changed files [within last few months or so] in the Facebook PHP/SDK, so you should also do this as well: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Update with the latest SDK, it will solve your problem.